# Unable to understand what the phrase means in this excerpt

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, modal-verbs

> "He is still watching, however" - she sighed - "and his gaze is
>   stronger. Not on us, but on the world. How much longer before he is
>   strong enough to..."
>   Nynaeve hunched her shoulders; suddenly she
>   could almost feel someone staring at her back. **It was one
>   explanation she would just as soon the Aes Sedai had not given her.**
>   Lan scouted their path down the river, but where before he had chosen
>   the way, now Moiraine did so, as surely as if she followed some unseen
>   track, footprints in air, the scent of memory. Lan only checked the
>   route she intended, to see that it was safe.
>
> > *The Wheel of Time: Book One - The Eye of The World (Chapter 28 - Footprints in Air)*

The phrase in bolds is what I am having a trouble understanding. Why does it feel like there is some part of the phrase missing? I'm thinking that the author intends to mean the following:

> It was one explanation she would have *arrived at* had the Aes Sedai not done so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Would* here does not express futurity; it reflects the original, now mostly obsolete, meaning of *will* to mean "wish" or "desire"—*Do what you will.* One use of this *volitive will* is as a main verb (not an auxiliary) in expressions like

- I **would rather** you didn't go by yourself.
- I **would sooner** you took me with you.
- I **would just as soon** we went together.

All of these have the general sense of 'prefer'. The 'past' form is used to mark these as implicitly conditional: "I don't have a choice, but if I did have a choice I *would* rather you didn't go by yourself." In the passage you cite, where the expression is used in a past-tense narrative, it also marks the past tense. Ordinarily modals in this "double past" situation are cast in the perfect, *would have*; but this is never done with these expressions, whose form is fixed. The pastness is sufficiently marked by the past perfect in the complement clause, *the Aes Sedai **had** not **given** her.*

In this case, the Aes Sedai (Moiraine) has given Nynaeve an explanation that Nynaeve now wishes she didn't know because it makes her more afraid. You could phrase it like this:

> It was one explanation she wished the Aes Sedai had not given her.

Comment: +1 Even closer perhaps is *would rather*, which in the part of the country I come from was often expressed *would sooner*.

Comment: @StoneyB I'd welcome an edit (or perhaps a self-answered question?) explaining the use of "would" as a main verb instead of an auxiliary. It's infrequent enough that it tends to surprise even native speakers.

Comment: As you wish - or will :)